# Issue in Creating a Task Due Date formula

Tags: apex, formula-field

My below formula is showing a syntax error, Can anyone plz suggest where its gone wrong in syntax. I am using it in process builder.

Whenn i tried it in formula editor, it showed , But i dont think anywhere its wrong. Thanks

**Error: Syntax error. Missing '='**

```
IF(
CASE( [Lead].Renewal_Month__c,
"January",1,
"February",2,
"March",3,
"April",4,     
"May",5,
"June", 6,
"July", 7,
"August", 8,
"September",9,
"October", 10,
"November", 11,
"December", 12,NULL)< MONTH(TODAY()),
IF(TEXT([Lead].Renewal_Month__c)="January",DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),12,1), 
DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,CASE([Lead].Renewal_Month__c,
"January",1,
"February",2,
"March",3,
"April",4, 
"May",5,
"June", 6,
"July", 7,
"August", 8,
"September",9,
"October", 10,
"November", 11,
"December", 12,NULL)-1,1)),
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-1, 1)
```

Comment: You are missing ) in the end of formula.

Answer (score 0):

Check below formula. Just formatted formula and added ) character in end.

```
IF(
    CASE( [Lead].Renewal_Month__c,
        "January",1,
        "February",2,
         "March",3,
        "April",4,     
        "May",5,
        "June", 6,
        "July", 7,
        "August", 8,
        "September",9,
        "October", 10,
        "November", 11,
        "December", 12,NULL
        )< MONTH(TODAY()),
    IF(
        TEXT([Lead].Renewal_Month__c)="January",
        DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),12,1), 
        DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,CASE([Lead].Renewal_Month__c,
                                    "January",1,
                                    "February",2,
                                    "March",3,
                                    "April",4, 
                                    "May",5,
                                    "June", 6,
                                    "July", 7,
                                    "August", 8,
                                    "September",9,
                                    "October", 10,
                                    "November", 11,
                                    "December", 12,NULL)-1,1
            )
        ),
        DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-1, 1)
    )
```